# Numerical algorithm for finding the inverse of a function

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, numerical-calculus

Is there a numerical method to approximate the inverse of a function for a given interval?

Thank you

Comment: Evaluate the function at some points `x` to get a vector of function values `y`, then swap `x` and `y`.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "function", that is, are you given a black box that returns a value for every value entered, are you given its analytic form etc. Also, please clarify what you would consider an "inverse", e.g. a lookup table as one of the answers proposed, an algorithm (e.g. Newton Raphson) for finding the inverse of a given value, etc.

Comment: The function is given in its analytic form as a function or subroutine in a programming language. Both answers below were very useful because I can approximate the derivative at a point numerically and then use series reversion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that you have $y=f(x)$ and you want to have an *approximation* $x=g(y)$ valid over a rnage $ a \leq  x \leq b$.

What you can do is to expand $f(x)$ as a Taylor series built around $x=c=\frac{a+b}2$ and get
$$y=f(c)+ f'(c)(x-c)+\frac{1}{2}  f''(c)(x-c)^2+\frac{1}{6} f'''(c)
   (x-c)^3+O\left((x-c)^4\right)$$ and then use [series reversion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html) to get
$$x=c+\frac{1}{f'(c)}(y-f(c))-\frac{ f''(c)}{2 f'(c)^3}(y-f(c))^2+\frac{ 3
   f''(c)^2-f'''(c) f'(c)}{6 f'(c)^5}(y-f(c))^3+O\left((y-f(c))^4\right)$$

Let us take the basic $f(x)=e^x$ with $a=-\frac 12$ and $b=\frac 12$
$$x=(y-1)-\frac{1}{2} (y-1)^2+\frac{1}{3} (y-1)^3+O\left((y-1)^4\right)$$ Now, for testing, assign a value to $x$ in order to get $y$ and recompute $x$ by the approximation formula. This will give
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -0.5 & -0.491184 \\
 -0.4 & -0.395969 \\
 -0.3 & -0.298573 \\
 -0.2 & -0.199684 \\
 -0.1 & -0.099978 \\
 +0.0 & +0.000000 \\
 +0.1 & +0.100028 \\
 +0.2 & +0.200511 \\
 +0.3 & +0.302933 \\
 +0.4 & +0.410535 \\
 +0.5 & +0.529304
\end{array}
\right)$$ For sure, with more terms in the first expansion the comparison will be batter.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use simple reverse interpolation. You start with a table of points $(x_i, y_i)_{0\leq i \leq n}$, where $y_i=f(x_i)$, then you reverse the table and interpolate. For example, if you start with a table of values for $e^x$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x_i & y_i \\
 -0.5 & 0.606531 \\
 -0.4 & 0.67032 \\
 -0.3 & 0.740818 \\
 -0.2 & 0.818731 \\
 -0.1 & 0.904837 \\
 0. & 1. \\
 0.1 & 1.10517 \\
 0.2 & 1.2214 \\
 0.3 & 1.34986 \\
 0.4 & 1.49182 \\
 0.5 & 1.64872 \\
\end{array}
\right) \to
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
y_i & x_i \\
 0.606531 & -0.5 \\
 0.67032 & -0.4 \\
 0.740818 & -0.3 \\
 0.818731 & -0.2 \\
 0.904837 & -0.1 \\
 1. & 0. \\
 1.10517 & 0.1 \\
 1.2214 & 0.2 \\
 1.34986 & 0.3 \\
 1.49182 & 0.4 \\
 1.64872 & 0.5 \\
\end{array}
\right),
$$
The interpolating polynomial for the second table is 
$$
p(y)=-0.0959517 y^{10}+1.11934 y^9-5.89122 y^8+18.4819 y^7-38.4598 y^6+55.8896
   y^5-58.1704 y^4+43.8458 y^3-24.158 y^2+10.4132 y-2.97439,
$$
which provides an approximation for the inverse function in the region [0.606531, 1.64872]. Below you can see the graph of the interpolation error for the inverse.

[image]

In practice, you should probably use piecewise lower order interpolation, Chebyshev nodes or a combination of both.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is extremely useful