# Approximate solutions to a transcendental equation of two variables

Tags: approximation, transcendental-equations, transcendental-functions

Say I have an equation of the form:
$$ y = A + B\sin (x) +C\sin (x+Dy) $$ on the domain $0<x<2\pi$.

I want to get $y$ as a function solely of $x$, i.e. remove the $y$-dependence from the R.H.S. This cannot be done analytically, but are there any useful tricks to analytically obtain approximate solutions? The trouble is that $x$ and $y$ can take on arbitrary values, i.e. I can't take them to be small and make a first-order approximation of $\sin$, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get $x$ solely in terms of $y$
$$y= A + B\sin(x) + C\sin(x+Dy)$$
$$y = A + B\sin(x) + C\sin(x)\cos(Dy) + C\sqrt{1-\sin^2 (x)}\sin(Dy)$$
$$z=\sin(x)$$
$$y = A + Bz + Cz\cos(Dy) + C\sqrt{1-z^2}\sin(Dy)$$
$$w=\cos(Dy)$$
$$y= A + Bz + Czw + C\sqrt{1-z^2}\sqrt{1-w^2}$$
Which yields:
$$z_{\pm}=\frac{\pm\sqrt{-C^2 \left(w^2-1\right) \left(-A^2+2 A y+B^2+2 B C w+C^2-y^2\right)}-A (B+C w)+B y+C w y}{B^2+2 B C w+C^2}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm left a little bit confused, though, on whether this can be inverted to get $y(x)$.

Comment: @intrepidspiff There are all sorts of numerical techniques to get solutions from the inverse. As you said originally, there is no analytic expression for the inverse. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3693157/numerical-algorithm-for-finding-the-inverse-of-a-function

Comment: Series reversion is good, but depending on what you want you might just want to calculate an array of solutions and then invert this

Answer (score 0):

Start expanding the last sine and use the tangent half-angle substitution
$x=2 \tan ^{-1}(t)$ to mka a quadratic equation in $t$
$$(a+c \sin (d y)-y)+2  (b+c \cos (d y))t+ (a-c \sin (d y)-y)t^2=0$$ which will show real solutions if
$$(b^2+c^2-a^2)+2 a y+2 b c \cos (d y)-y^2 >0$$ If this is the case, you have two solutions $t_\pm$ and $x_\pm=2 \tan ^{-1}(t_\pm)$.

There is no way to get $y(x)$.

Comment: Brilliant! If I may ask, how on earth did you think to make the tangent half-angle substitution?